# what is the function of model.compile?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

So I am making an indigenous language translator using a per letter data sets. I have minimal knowledge on machine learning and only have made a 2 category image classifier. originally these are my codes it works fine. I get the classification report and confusion matrix. it shows my all my parameters and non trainable parameters here are the codes

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
print(Image.__file__)
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\BAYBAYIN\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\BAYBAYIN\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 51600
nb_validation_samples = 12900
epochs = 1
batch_size = 100

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

from keras.applications.xception import Xception
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = Xception(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

print("PRINTING OUT CLASSIFICATION REPORT AND CONFUSION MATRIX")

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)
print(cm)

plt.imshow(cm)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.imshow(np.random.random((48,48)), interpolation='nearest')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,48), ['A', 'BA', 'KA', 'GA', 'HA', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
              '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
              '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32',
              '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44'])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,48),['A', 'BA', 'KA', 'GA', 'HA', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
              '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
              '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32',
              '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44'])

plt.show()
```

I just have a problem with these specific lines of codes

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I dont know what its function is or what is it for but what i suspect is that it should be a categorical crossentropy because im running a multiple image classifier but when changing it to a `categorical_ crossentropy` i get many errors even when trying `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

does anyone know if i could just continue using these codes or should i change it because im also having problem with the accuracy its really low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model.compile is just for configuring the model with loss function, optimization, loss metrics, loss weigths etc)

You should definitely be using categorical cross entropy ; can you paste the error - your model can be performing poorly for various reasons.

Comment: hiya sorry for not getting in touch heres the error when using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 43 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values:`

Comment: `34 6 1 13 0 4 33 4 6 28 29 21 13 30 20 38 1 22 40 7 23 41 35 16 23 14 9 42 29 7 23 25 43 7 0 7 1 34 8 0 1 2 20 14 23 24 37 19 24 4 2 0 40 37 0 23 17 1 2 38 9 4 22 14 7 9 15 23 23 36 28 8 43 14 18 15 41 25 33 41 10 14 6 16 23 28 34 34 10 21 30 25 5 15 39 40 39 29 22 32
  [[node loss/dense_1_loss/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at \Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\TRANSLATOR\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_31126]`

Comment: `Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph`